# Проблемма с добавлением и извлечением данных из массива JavaScript

Tags: javascript

У меня возникла проблема при добавлении элемента в массив.

```
let editors = [];    
function CreateEditor(){
const editorsAll = document.querySelectorAll('.comment_editor');
let edit;

for(let editor of editorsAll){
   const script_id = `${editor.id}_script`;
   const labelName = document.querySelector(`[for$="editor.id"]`);

   editor.nextSibling.remove();
   if(labelName){
       labelName.style.float = "none"
   }

   let text = document.getElementById(script_id).textContent;
   const config = JSON.parse(
       text,(key, value) => {
           if(value.toString().includes('/')){
               return new RegExp(value.replaceAll('/',''));
           }
           return value;
       }
   );
    ClassicEditor.create(editor,config).then(response => {
       editors.push(response.data)
   });
}


}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    CreateEditor();
    console.log(editors)
});
```

console.log(editors) выводит Array[] то есть не добавляется в него ни чего.
Однако если посмотреть дальше при нажатии на стрелке то будет это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите что не так и как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Очень похоже, что `ClassicEditor.create` асинхронный. Вы просто не дожидаетесь добавления элемента в массив.

Comment: то есть мне нужно использовать что то типа async editors.push(editor) или лучше await?

Comment: Придется использовать сразу оба, т.к. одно без другого не работает или через цепочку вызовов .then()  передавать результат